# Is Schedule C appropriate for single-owner S Corporation elected company (Domestic For-Profit Corporation) registered in Washington, D.C.?

Tags: united-states, taxes, s-corporation

Can I, as the owner of an S Corporation that is registered in the District of Columbia as a For-Profit Domestic Corporation, use form 1040 Schedule C?

Two tax professionals have used this form; for the past two years since business started; though checking since others said that is wrong.

- No employees
- Business started in 2012 and both years filed the following forms

  - IRS form - 8879 - e-file signature authorization
  - IRS form - 1040 - U.S. individual income tax return
  - IRS form - 1040 Schedule A - itemized deductions
  - IRS form - 1040 Schedule C - profit or loss from business (sole proprietorship)
  - IRS form - 1040 Schedule C-EZ - net profit from business (this is not related to m business but my wife's business and I think we can ignore this as it does not have my company's info)
  - IRS form - 1040 Schedule SE - self-employment tax
  - IRS form - 1040 Schedule SE - self-employment tax ( for my wife so I think we can ignore )
  - IRS form - 8829 - expenses for business use of your home ( I have home-based business )
  - IRS form - 4562 - Depreciation and amortization
  - DC Form - D-40 SUB - individual income tax return
  - DC Form - d-2210 - underpayment of estimated income tax by individuals
  - DC form - D-40E Sub DC

Thank you in advance for all your guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not use Schedule C for a Corporation.

If you treat the business as a sole proprietorship, i.e.: not a separate legal entity and not a separate financial entity - then you can. If that's how you treat your corporation, then you can continue using Schedule C, but there's no reason whatsoever to continue being a corporation either since the corporate liability protection veil is likely to be long gone.

Generally, corporations file form 1120, S-Corporations file form 1120S.